# Pattern Rules and Multiple Directories in Makefiles

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I am having trouble with using pattern rules and applying them across dependencies and targets in multiple directories. Here is an example to illustrate my problem.

Consider the following directory structure

```
|- dir 1
|  - file1.A
|- dir 2
|  - file2.A
|- dir 3
|  - dir 4
|    - file4.A
```

I want to be able to specify a pattern rule, that can be applied to all *.A files.

```
%.B: %.A
  myscript $<
```

What is the best way to specify this?

I tried the following, as a hack, but it gives me an error that I am mixing implicit and static rules.

```
*/%.B: */%.A:
  myscript $<

*/*/%B: */%.A:
  myscript $<
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: The first rule works, if you use it correctly (i.e. `make dir1/file1.B`). What are you trying to do?

Comment: I want a single rule `all` that I can run to create all the %.B file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
A_FILES := $(shell find . -type f -name '*.A')
B_FILES := $(patsubst %.A,%.B,$(A_FILES))

all: $(B_FILES)

%.B: %.A
    myscript $<
```

On some platforms this will work:

```
A_FILES := $(wildcard **/*.A)
```