# Makefile pattern rule with multiple sources in different subdirectories

Tags: makefile

I want a pattern rule for a Makefile for turning several sources into a single object.

So instead of a filename like `foo.c` I have a folder name `foo/`.

Additionally, there's path of the directory stem `src/bar/foo/` where not only the shared `src/` needs to be ignored but also the variable `bar/`.

### Directory Structure

I have several objects to create - let's call them this:

```
bin/lib1.so
bin/lib2.so
bin/lib3.so
```

The source directory has a structure like this with folders grouping the libs:

- src/

  - foo/

    - lib1/

      - a.c
      - b.c
  - bar/

    - lib2/

      - d.c
      - e.c
    - lib3/

      - f.c
      - g.c

If the grouping of libs didn't exist it would be straightforward, but it does exist.

### Makefile

The targets get built by `make all` which is given for this example explicitly (I actually use `shell find` as in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21224554/pattern-rules-and-multiple-directories-in-makefiles), because there's several of them, but for this example I keep it simple):

```
all: bin/lib1.so bin/lib2.so bin/lib3.so
```

Now I would like to clean up the Makefile by creating a pattern rule for making all of these targets, kind of like this:

```
bin/%.so: $$(wildcard src/*/%/*.c)
   # testing the rule:
   echo $< > $@
```

But this doesn't work.

I'm skipping the step of c->o for simplicity because the point is linking together several files.

There's [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1963802/makefile-pattern-rules-and-directories) which has a similar problem of subdirectories, but it's only about 1:1 mapping of files instead of n:1, and I couldn't get it to work for my problem.

### Desired Result

To test the rule it should just show in each target file what sources went into it:

*bin/lib1.so*

```
src/foo/lib1/a.c
src/foo/lib1/b.c
```

*bin/lib2.so*

```
src/bar/lib2/d.c
src/bar/lib2/e.c
```

*bin/lib3.so*

```
src/bar/lib3/f.c
src/bar/lib3/g.c
```

Comment: Could you share the entire content of your Makefile please ?

Comment: I already did, I created the minimal example specifically to exhibit only the problem.

`all: bin/lib1.so bin/lib2.so bin/lib3.so`

`bin/%.so: $$(wildcard src/*/%/*.c)`
|   # testing the rule:`
|   echo $< > $@` The current complicated Makefile isn't needed, the example is sufficiently complete.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a working version that supports one or multiple `C` files as input:

```
bin/%.so: src/*/%/*.c
    @echo "START"
    @echo $^
    @echo $@
    @echo "END"

all: bin/lib1.so bin/lib2.so bin/lib3.so
```

Result:

```
$ make

START
src/foo/lib1/main.c
bin/lib1.so
END
START
src/bar/lib2/plip.c src/bar/lib2/plop.c
bin/lib2.so
END
START
src/bar/lib3/kilo.c
bin/lib3.so
END
```